# Why is get_env() treating my boolean environment variable as a string?

Tags: php, wordpress

I upgraded my Wordpress instance from 4.5 to 4.8, and for some reason my boolean environment variable is now returning as a string of "false" rather than `false`.  Since my PHP version hasn't changed, I'm a bit mystified at the change.  More importantly however, about going forward, what's the best way to manage getting booleans into PHP via environment vars?

Here's the .env line I have:

```
WP_FORCE_SSL_ADMIN=false
```

Here's the line I had in my wp-config.php that is returning `true` due to string conversion.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', getenv('WP_FORCE_SSL_ADMIN'));
```

Here's the var_dump:

```
["WP_FORCE_SSL_ADMIN"]=&gt;
string(5) "false"
```

I know that I can simply refactor the define to account for the string conversion, but I'm bothered that I don't understand what changed when nothing should have.  This worked fine on for wordpress version 4.5.

Looking for an answer to explain the best method for passing boolean vars from my environment into PHP, or do I always have to account for the string conversion?

Comment: Wordpress4.8 probably isn't passing `INI_SCANNER_TYPED` when parsing the `.env` file - **EDIT** Totally misread the question, my bad.

Comment: Hmmm.... [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) say that `getenv` returns a _string_ (or `FALSE` if doesn't exist) - so you apparently will always have to account for string conversion.

Comment: I read that too.  Must be that WP changed how it interprets FORCE_SSL_ADMIN to no longer interpret the string "false" as false.  Sigh...

Comment: I doubt that.  That `define` line is 100% PHP, nothing to do with PHP at all.  I'm guessing you were _not_ picking up the environment variable in the first place, which is why it was returning `FALSE` (boolean), so it seemed to be doing what you wanted, but actually wasn't seeing it all.

Comment: right, but WP is the one using the variable created by the define?  I'm guessing that PHP always stored the string "false", but WP is the one that is using that variable differently.  This makes sense since the change is related to my upgrade.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just in case someone comes here looking for the answer to how I solved it, what I did was simply do a comparison to the string of "true".

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', strtolower(getenv('WP_FORCE_SSL_ADMIN')) === "true");
```

While this works, it still doesn't feel quite right to me, like I'm missing something.

Comment: Good answer but works only for "true", not for "TRUE", "True" etc.. which are valid values

Comment: It's a hack in any case

Comment: @RameshNavi I added `strtolower()` around the `getenv()` method, which should solve that issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
But it worked like below:

```
$isDebug = filter_var($_ENV['DEBUG']??false, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
//OR
$isDebug = filter_var(getenv('DEBUG')??false, FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN);
```